# Discord Bot - Forward message from one server channel to another

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm looking help to forward all the messages from one server channel to another server channel and I can't seem to find the resources to write out the js. Would appreciate if someone could help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const bot = new Discord.Client();
    
    let myChannel = '79095670112085608' //my target channel
    
    const token = 'myToken';
    
    
    
    bot.on('message', gotMessage);
    
    function gotMessage(msg) {
        bot.channels.fetch(myChannel)
           .then(channel => channel.send(msg.content))
           .catch(console.error);
 //FIXED problem1: forward new message to another server channel 
 //problem2: how to stop infinite looping for the same message to another server channel
    }
    bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Be careful about including credentials in your question, if your token is visible somebody could log in as your bot.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) class has a property called [channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) that you can use to get a [ChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager).
The ChannelManager has a method called [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) that can be used to retrieve a channel. Assuming that the ID of the channel you have is a [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel), you can use the [send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method to pass on messages.

When we put this together, it might look like this:

```js
function gotMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.channel.id !== myChannel) {
        bot.channels.fetch(myChannel)
           .then(channel => channel.send(msg.content))
           .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure thing. I updated my answer to handle that case. Before forwarding the message this checks to make sure that the channel the message is from isn't equal to `myChannel`. Let me know if it works. @xfactormy

Comment: Greatly appreciate the help! I managed to get the text message forwarded to a target channel in another server!

Great tip on the myChannel, didn't thought of that until you mention it! Giving it a try now. Thanks again!